# Font not displaying properly despite being embedded

Tags: fonts, pdf, adobe-acrobat, scribus

I have created a document in Scribus which I exported to PDF, embedding all the fonts. However, in some applications, one of the fonts (Montserrat) does not display properly – it looks like some sort of glyphs:

[image]

Above is a screenshot from the online version of Adobe Acrobat. The weird thing is that the font looks right for about 30 seconds and then changes to this. Also, in the Google Drive PDF viewer and the desktop version of Acrobat Reader (free version), it looks normal. When I copy the "text" to word, the original words display.

Is there anything I can do about this? (I want to send the file for printing, so it is important that the fonts are, well, actual text).

The font information for Montserrat (and all its styles) is:

> Montserrat-*[font style]*
> Type: TrueType
> Encoding: Custom

If it is important, I think I downloaded the font from the [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) website. The other fonts in the document don't experience such issues (though Montserrat is my main font).

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech support is generally off-topic here. Maybe contact the developers of the applications which aren't displaying it properly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi, welcome from me too. Firstly, please always give "the basics" when you request such technical help. As Billy pointed out, this is not the best place, but there are friendly people here, willing to help. (And Billy is also very friendly indeed). So we could help you better, if you include your version of Scribus, your OS, your format of PDF that you chose on export etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do about this?

It looks like you got issues with your set-up or just with this one font. As you need to print (when?) there is one fix, that you can do right now:

In your dialog for "Save as PDF" please opt in the "Fonts" tab for "Outline All Fonts" instead of "Embed or Subset". If you are seeing other options, you might be using a different version of Scribus or other OS. Just find the equivalent.

This will give you very reliable output and what you see, is what they will print.

There is one dis-advantage: Your print-shop cannot edit the (PDF) document for you. So if you have a deal, where they do the proof-reading and minor corrections, that will not work any more.

That said, I have personally used only "Outline all Fonts" for several years, for online publishing and for commercial printing. And even producing in a minority language (with "exotic characters") we never had any issues ever with display or printing of our documents.

If you want to research your underlying issue with the unexpected behaviour, I suggest to go to the Scribus.net website and find the e-mail list for user-support (I am also on that). And that is a great place to research deeper question, that are not so well suited for this graphics exchange. Remember to give as much detail there as you find relevant (and then a little more) and people can help you better.